# Diagnosing high wait times for FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX on Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, locking, azure-sql-database

Of late, we have had issues wherein there is a huge spike in the `FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX` wait counts. We've seen wait times close to 250 seconds for some user requests.
We employ the full text search feature of SQL Azure for the search functionality in our cloud service.

What we have observed is that when the `FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX` wait counts spike, the DB performance dips. We start seeing query execution time increasing greatly, and more and more queries build up in the queue.

As per documentation, the only thing that I could find on this wait type was:

> FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX: Full-text is waiting on an fdhost control operation.
>   Documented for informational purposes only. Not supported. Future
>   compatibility is not guaranteed.

In all the other blogs or documents, what I’ve read was this wait type is benign and can be ignored.
I wanted to confirm if:

- This can really be ignored?
- What can be the cause of the high wait counts, how can I debug it? During the period when there were high wait counts the SQL Server processor was stable (no spikes) and so was the request count going to the DB.

Any pointers to debug this further?

Comment: as much as I like SQL Server i wouldn't use FULL Text search fol large piles of GOLD!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please verify that resource consumption is not reaching the limits while updating a column indexed by Full-text search and thus throttling is occurring creating spikes on that wait?

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'CPU Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Log Write Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Physical Data Read Fit Percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
```

--service level objective (SLO) of 99.9% <= go to next tier

If the workload of this database is I/O intensive, Premium tiers are intended for those workloads.

Comment: Our database is already in premium tier in Azure SQL! (running at P11 currently). For day-to-day operations our SQL server performs very well, in terms of CPU/memory etc. There are these short spikes on wait times for FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX which we are trying to diagnose.